# Can't connect to Postgres database on Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin, dbeaver

I'm working on a NestJS with GraphQL project following the [Fernando Herrera Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/nest-graphql/). [Link of the repository.](https://github.com/Klerith/graphql-nest-anylist/tree/fin-seccion-5) I followed along every single step until I tried to connect to the Docker-PostgreSQL database.

The database itself is created and it seems to be okay.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: anylistDB
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    container_name: anylistDB
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

This is the terminal of Docker:

[docker terminal with the message: database system is ready to accept connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZVFR.png)
As you can see there is a log telling me that the "databse system is ready to accept connections"

This is the error I received on Table Plus and other clients:

[connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYDI8.png)

I tried PGadmin and Dbeaver as well, both gave me the same error.

I tried to set the 'host' field of the 3 sql clients the value 'postgres' and the value '127.0.0.1'.

I tried several versions of docker and postgres images as the 14.4, 15.2 and 15.2-alpine, the error persist.

I tried to compose the container with and without the -d flag: `docker-compose up -d`

I also tried to write down the db-password and db-name into the docker-compose file in order to dismiss an environment variables error, but it didn't work out as well.

I also tried to clone the same repository on my mac and it worked out perfectly.

And finally, I don't know If has something to do with it, but I shut down the windows defender and the antivirus firewall.

Comment: Are your clients running locally on the host machine running the docker container or are they also running in containers on the same docker network?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and show the complete setup. In particular, please show the value of variable `${DB_NAME}`.

Comment: Hi @ChrisDoyle how can I check this out? I don't know if I'm understanding correctly your question.

Comment: @AlexanderRomero you haven't specified any username in your postgres container, only password and db name exists. try adding it and see if it works.

Comment: The name of the database is `AnyList`, not `anyListDB` - that is the name of the container.

Comment: @Turing85 Sorry for the mistake, I posted it wrong, already corrected but the error persist.

Comment: user: `postgres!=anylistDB`.

Comment: @TaimoorMirza Already tested, I'll update the post with your advice but is still not working.

Comment: @xerx593 What do you mean by that?

Comment: @xerx593 So what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: can you clean the volume? (if credentials already set/db initialized, environment variables won't have much effect..)

Comment: @xerx593 How can clean the volume? I tried to remove the folder that docker compose create and generated after that.

Comment: `rm -rf ./postgres` (in your docker compose workspace ... `volumes:...` ;)

Comment: @xerx593 and then 'docker compose up -d' again, isn't it?